# Requiring a JavaScript Node.js module in TypeScript (allowJs' is not set)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron, pcsc

I have an Angular2 app inside Electron. Now, I would like to use the `@pokusew/pcsclite` library to use NFC functionality. This library uses native Node.js modules.

When I try to *require* the library in my component.ts like this:

```
declare var pcsclite: any;
var pcsclite = require('../../../node_modules/@pokusew/pcsclite/');
```

I get and error that says:

> error TS6143: Module '../..' was resolved to '../../lib/pcsclite.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.

On the other hand, if I try to import the library via a <\script>-Tag in the index.html I get an error that says:

> **ZoneAwareError** Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:...

Finally, if I `var pcsclite = require('@pokusew/pcsclite');` in the `main.js`, then it works, but then I don't have access to it from inside my Angular app.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Add the `allowJs` option in your `tsconfig.json` like this:
as [fabian lauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3861083/fabian-lauer) said  also add `outDir` option to specify where your compiled files will be:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./built", <--- add this
        "allowJs": true,  <--- and this
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, then I get other errors for each of my .js files. "error TS5055: Cannot write file '...components.js' because it would overwrite input file"

Comment: @Phil That's probably because you either didn't set `"outDir"` or you set the `"outDir"` in `tsconfig.json` to the same directory as the source files.

Comment: Ok, I set up the whole project again with Angular CLI to avoid these kind of problems. Using `allowJs` I am now able to import the module using `import * as pcsclite from ".../node_modules/..."`, but when I try to use it `const pcsc = pcsclite();` I get this error in the console: `TypeError: exists is not a function`(vendor.bundle.js) and some warnings regarding bindings.js when compiling.

Comment: i can't use `pcsclite` becaue Im on windows, try `import * as pcsclite from "pcsclite";` or `import {} from "pcsclite";`

Comment: @Phil Since your original question has been answered, you could accept this answer as the correct one ;-)

Comment: @Fabian Lauer, yes, instead I will open a new problem for the specific problem that appears now. And thanks to both of you for your help!