# Typescript import * from .js | flatpickr.js | .net core

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

```
import * as Flatpickr from 'flatpickr';
import { ru as Russian } from '../../lib/flatpickr/dist/l10n/ru.js';
```

i got the error: --allowJs is not set.

i tried the solution posted here
[Requiring a JavaScript Node.js module in TypeScript (allowJs' is not set)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42867688/requiring-a-javascript-node-js-module-in-typescript-allowjs-is-not-set/45933562#45933562)

```
"outDir": "./built", <--- add this
"allowJs": true,  <--- and this
```

Now i cant build my project in VS2017, because nuget packages are not found. Am i missing something?

My nugets are working fine when outdir/rootdir are set to "wwwroot", but then i get this "Cannot write file '...components.js' because it would overwrite input file"